# Style WPF Tree in two different ways in one window

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, styles

Hi I am trying to have two styles for two wpf trees. But when I add my sytle to one tree (see image on the left side) it only applies the style to one level. How can i have the "plus line" style for every level?

[image]

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView1" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource Style1}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
```

in:

```
 <Windows.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
           ...
        </Style>
</Windwos.Resoures>
```

Comment: In your TreeView you have the container style set to "Style" but the resource key is "Style1". Could that be the issue?

Comment: Have your tried to use the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`?